# Warning about reflective access of structural type member in Scala

Tags: scala

What does this warning mean:

> reflective access of structural type member method getMap should be enabled

The warning includes a reference to the scala docs but I don't understand how my code is related to the explanation. (Specifically the explanation mentions reflection... how is my code using reflection?)

I have this: (Scala 2.11.2)

```
object getMap {
    implicit def fromOptionToConvertedVal[T](o:Option[T]) = new {
        def getMap[R] (doWithSomeVal:(T) => R) = new {
            def orElse(handleNone: => R) = o match {
                case Some(value) => doWithSomeVal(value)
                case None => handleNone
            }
        }
    }   
}

import getMap._
val i:Option[Int] = Some(5)
val x = i getMap (_*2) orElse 1
```

This generates the warning below:

```
[warn] /Users/Greg/git/Favorites-Demo/src/main/scala/com/rs/server/ThriftServer.scala:34: reflective access of structural type member method getMap should be enabled
[warn] by making the implicit value scala.language.reflectiveCalls visible.
[warn] This can be achieved by adding the import clause 'import scala.language.reflectiveCalls'
[warn] or by setting the compiler option -language:reflectiveCalls.
[warn] See the Scala docs for value scala.language.reflectiveCalls for a discussion
[warn] why the feature should be explicitly enabled.
[warn] val x = i getMap (_*2) orElse 1
[warn]           ^
[warn] /Users/Greg/git/Favorites-Demo/src/main/scala/com/rs/server/ThriftServer.scala:34: reflective access of structural type member method orElse should be enabled
[warn] by making the implicit value scala.language.reflectiveCalls visible.
[warn] val x = i getMap (_*2) orElse 1
[warn]                        ^
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think what's going on is that the `new { ... }` objects are structurally typed, which require reflection to implement.

The underlying reason is that Scala structural typing allows objects to be treated as if they are instances of many types according to which methods they actually have (like duck typing). The JVM allows exactly one type so methods that are not part of the object's underlying type have to be accessed via something other than a normal virtual method call. The mechanism that's used in this case is reflection.

When the scala compiler sees an invocation of a method that's being called on a structurally typed object it (modulo some optimizations) translates a method call like:

```
a.f(b, c)
```

to

```
a.getClass
    .getMethod("f", Array(classOf[B], classOf[C]))
    .invoke(a, Array(b, c))
```

Example taken from [the place where the technique was described](http://gilles.dubochet.ch/publications/2009_dubochet_structural_types.pdf).

The Scala team decided to enforce an opt-in policy for advanced features. `reflectiveCalls` happens to be one of them as documented in this [SIP](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nlkvpoIRkx7at1qJEZafJwthZ3GeIklTFhqmXMvTX9Q/edit#heading=h.p8y95rkd4ydi)