# code block following creation of new object in scala

Tags: scala, constructor

I have a constructor defined as

```
class Test{ var i = 0; println("constructor"); }
```

And I call it as

```
val t = new Test { println("codeblock"); i = 7; }
```

The result of this is:

```
constructor
codeblock
defined class Test
t: Test = $anon$1@4a7b4f79
res3: Int = 7
```

So I see that the code block on the same line as new is executed as if it was part of the constructor. I am not familiar with this.

Could some one clarify this behaviour and/or point to reference that explains the semantics at play here? I am not sure how to google this - looking for `code block on same line as constructor call scala` doesn'y help much.

Comment: You'd have to google "general instance creation expression". http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#instance-creation-expressions  and see also http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-036

Comment: thanks! that looks interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's roughly equivalent to this:

```
class Test{ var i = 0; println("constructor"); }

class TestImpl extends Test {
  println("codeblock")
  i = 7
}

scala> new TestImpl
constructor
codeblock
res8: TestImpl = TestImpl@6baf697c

scala> res8.i
res9: Int = 7
```

So you can see that initialization order comes from more abstract to a more concrete class.

To highlight @som-snytt's comment pointing to Scala Language Specification: [general instance creation expression](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#instance-creation-expressions)

Comment: ah, which is why the type is `$anon$` . why is this better than `val t = new Test; t.i = 7` ?

Comment: it's not better or worse - the chosen approach depends on your task. As I recall in Java they usually initialize stuff in constructor. From Scala perspective, there is no point to have `var` in most cases - you can replace it with immutable data (vals, case classes). However, some Java-styled dependencies might require proper initialization (just a regular, not "case" class is encouraged then); logging is another good example.

Comment: thanks. ran into this when looking at some scalafx code.

Comment: @som-snytt See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787871/warning-about-reflective-access-of-structural-type-member-in-scala . Wouldn't this mean that there's refection happening when `new SomeType {...}` initialization?

Comment: @divbyzero it would take place only if you  add some new members during 'new', they (members) gonna be acessed with reflection then and you'll see a warning. As of 2.12.1 scala. That is what I meant by "roughly equivalent", if TestImpl has some new members, you actually get a structural type Test {def newMember} as a type of your res8.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Scala follows Right most first to left order overrides. meaning if you have `new A{B} with C with D with E` init sequence will be E->D->C->B->A. this is very important if you are dealing with inheritance diamond problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem

Comment: @linehrr though you’re right about linearization in general, I think OP’s question proves that initialization  order would be E -> D -> C -> **A -> B** if I understand your syntax correctly. P. S. (Unrelated but fun) Is it only me or did u too notice that functional programmers tend to fail diamond problem questions on the interviews? :D

Comment: @dk14 you are right, A->B, made a typo. and also, I think FP guys don't even know about diamond problem, since they don't care, LOL.

Comment: @linehrr (not caring about modularity might make one functional but not a programmer lol)